# Is there a way to specify N fields as the unique key in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, indexing

I am trying to figure out how to use two or more fields in a document as a unique key for the document.

I have a document similar to this, specified in Java, using Spring Boot annotations:

```
@Document(collection = "Records")
class MyRecord {
  @Id
  String name;
  String jobType;
  String group;
  Long numTasks;
  ...
}
```

Perhaps I'm missing something, as I'm fairly new to MongoDB. The closes thing I've found is Indexes, but it doesn't seem clear that indexes behave the same as unique keys. I want to be able to query on two fields. Each of those fields doesn't need to be unique, but each pairing of those two fields should be unique through the collection. What isn't clear is if indexes will force that uniqueness.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does have unique compound indexes as seen https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index

Sprint Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/CompoundIndex.html

This would seem to make your code something like

```
@Document(collection = "Records")
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'name': 1, 'jobType': 1}", unique=true)
class MyRecord {
  @Id
  String name;
  String jobType;
  String group;
  Long numTasks;
  ...
}
```